# Proper use of DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My application shall allow the user to look at a table (aka "map") 14 x 28 with X and Y axis loaded from a microcontroller (MCU). This can be edited and sent back into microcontroller. I have two arrays that contain the GUI map and MCU map, which allows any differences to be flagged.

I have a DataGridView that displays the data. This works with initial data. I simply can't get new data to be updated into the DataGridView. The DataGridView is in a Form within an Mdi Child. Here's how I command the changes:

```
'CalDataTable is the DataGridView
'Map is an array of Single

CalDataTable.Rows.Clear()
CalDataTable.Columns.Clear()

For j As Integer = 1 To 16   'Loop through data and populate table
  For i As Integer = 1 To 24
    CalDataTable.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value = Map(i - 1, j - 1)
  Next
Next
```

This event is launched from a click in the menuStrip of the Mdi Parent, and the data does not update. However, when I launch the update through a button event within the MDI Child form, it works like a charm.

Am I using the wrong tool or what else could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.Rows.Clear()` and `.Columns.Clear()` does more work than just emptying the data. It actually removes the rows and columns from the grid. There are no longer any cells in the grid at all. You don't want that. This isn't like Excel, where the workspace is still there even when you delete things. You need the column definitions and row records to still exist.

Instead, loop through and reset each cell to an empty value, whether that's `0`, an empty string, or something else. Or, since it looks like the following loop will visit every cell anyway, just remove the `Clear()` lines completely.

Comment: I have omitted some code for simplicity, but I have reset the table with new rows, columns, etc. The problem is I simply cannot change the data in the cells. Let's say Cell 1,1 is displaying 15. I run the the line `CalDataTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = 35` and the cell still displays 15. Unless of course I execute the command from a button click. That is, the difference is between executing from MDI parent form or on a button within the mdi child form.

Comment: Try calling the `.Invalidate()` function for the grid. That will force it to repaint with new data. Alternatively, if you are populating the grid initially via the `DataSource` property, update that datasource rather than individual cells.

Comment: Adding the .Invalidate() is getting us closer. Old data is displayed until the form is clicked, where everything updates. Any ideas what could be missing here?

Comment: This means we need to force a repaint (WM_PAINT message) for the form.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried .Refresh(), .Activate(), .DoEvents()... Nothing has worked except for clicking on the form.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I found the issue. I was making changes calling the Form class itself. By calling the form instance, this made all the difference.

Comment: @rmaier yet another reason default form instances shouldn't have been included in VB.NET